# CSS or Javascript href hover (or mouseover) showing additional clickable links

Tags: javascript, css

I have a need to present a user with various editing options when they hover over a link. I think I have seen it done somewhere, but I can't seem to find an example. I've built a quasi-example here, but it doesn't quite work right. Also, my example has me sort of cheating with margins of -45 just to get a working example.

Here is a snapshot of how my code functions (code below).

[image]

Here is a snapshot of how I would like it to function.

[image]

The mouseover (or something similar) would result in:

1. the bulleted item would change to a different image icon
2. a set of icons would appear to edit, delete, etc. and these would be selectable/clickable in the white space to the right of the href link.
3. the links would be of various lengths so I am trying not to use absolute positioning.

I realize the second requirement might not be possible if it's based on a real hover or mouseover because once the user is no longer mousing-over or hovering-over the active link, the icons should disappear and would become unselectable. Is there someway to make the whole row (maybe the link plus 45 pixels next to it) remain hoverable/mouseover-able? I do not want the user to have to click to see the options.

Is something like this possible with pure CSS? Or, is there a Javascript solution?

```
    <head>
    <style>
    <!-- 
    #NewsGroup1 {width:600px;}
    a { text-decoration: none; } /* color: #006ab7; */
    a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

    #myoptions {
        display: none; margin-left:-45px;
    }

    a:hover + #myoptions {
        display: inline;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="NewsGroup1">
    <ul>
        <li>News</li>
            <ul>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="link1.htm">Link 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><div id="myoptions">&nbsp;<a href="#">A</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">M</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">E</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">D</a></div></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="link2.htm">Link 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><div id="myoptions">&nbsp;<a href="#">A</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">M</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">E</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">D</a></div></li>
        </ul>

    </ul></div>
    </body>
```

**UPDATED CODE: 12/12/2011**

```
<html>
<style>
#box1 {width:100px; background-color:yellow;}
li a img  {display:none; margin-right:3px;}
li:hover img {display:inline-block;}
a {margin-right:20px;}
a.extras {margin-right:3px;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="box1">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work like that, just set the sources for the two image elements:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
li > img{
    display:none;
}
li:hover img {
    display:inline-block;
}
a{
    margin-right:20px;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a>Link1</a><img/><img/></li>
    <li><a>Link2</a><img/><img/></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This gets me on the right track. I need the hover images to be linkable. I added an extra line of CSS, but it doesn't seem to accomplish the task. My fix is show on bullet 1 and is not implemented on bullet 2 and 3. I found icons on the web to use as a test.

How can I adjust the code to make the hover images linkable? My adjusted code has been put up on the original post under "UPDATED CODE".

Comment: I edited your code, just change the "li > img" to "li > a img", then your fix with the <a>'s works. :)

Comment: Tom: Excellent help. Thank you. I was wondering if there is a way to get the 'li:hover img' to float/overflow beyond a predefined DIV. I've updated the code above (today, 12/12/2011). The new code has a small, yellow bounding box. When you hover over the <LI>, the images appear as intended, but since the box is narrow, the images appear on the next line. Is there a way to trump the yellow bounding and have it so that the 'li:hover img' is not bound by the bounding box?

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle that illustrates the issue at:
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/a88Cz/

Answer (score 0):

You have the most part there, it seems to work. All i'd do is add the icon images you want between the `#myoptions` elements.

**Update**

I've created a JSFiddle with wht you want. Obviously change the images and stuff

http://jsfiddle.net/MaCqw/

There is no Javascript invloved here

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd need Javascript, perhaps not. Check out jQuery show:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

This is my personal favorite, and it's pretty easy to implement.

Comment: I don't understand why I got a thumbs down. This is a plausible solution.