# LI hover and display extra links on a separate layer?

Tags: css

In a previous question, I solved a need to have a LI hover which shows extra links (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364110/css-or-javascript-href-hover-or-mouseover-showing-additional-clickable-links).

Now, I am trying to solve a need to have the UL and LI's wrapped in a narrow DIV. Currently, when the hidden links display, they wrap to the next line. I would like them to overflow as needed to allow the links to appear on the same line without altering the width of the wrapper. In other words, I would like it to hover using something like a z-index that present the hover line as a separate layer. Is this possible with CSS?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/a88Cz/

```
<html>
<style>
#box1 {width:100px; background-color:yellow; z-index:1}
li a img  {display:none; margin-right:3px; z-index:1000}
li:hover img {display:inline-block;}
a {margin-right:20px;}
a.extras {margin-right:3px;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="box1">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/doc-txt.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/flag.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/bubble.png" /></a><a class="extras" href="#"><img src="http://urlgreyhot.com/files/icons/png/12x12/checkbox.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wTwAd/

Comment: or this? http://jsfiddle.net/WcQYk/

Answer (score 0):

While the fiddle I [linked in my comment](http://jsfiddle.net/wTwAd/) works as a quick and dirty solution using `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: visible`, I believe this is more like what you had in mind:

http://jsfiddle.net/wTwAd/1/

It uses an absolutely positioned div of your links positioned outside each list item.

Comment: Hi jblasco: Actually, your first solution behaves more like what I had in mind. I've adjusted the length of the link text to illustrate. I want the links to appear right next to the text. The only problem with your quick and dirty solution here is that the icons that fall outside of the wrapper are not hyperlinked. Here is the updated Fiddle. Is there a way to make these links really hyperlinked? This solution is so close.
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/wTwAd/2/

Comment: jblasco: The second solution looks nice for link text that is uniform in length, but with the varying widths, it doesn't quite work as I had intended. Here is my updated Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/wTwAd/4/

Answer (score 0):

I altered your markup to make it easier to work with:

```
<div id="box1">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></li>
        </ul>      
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#box1 {width:60px; background-color:yellow;}
#box1 ul > li {position:relative;}
#box1 ul li ul{display:none; background:yellow;}
#box1 ul ul li {display:inline;}
#box1 ul > li:hover ul{display:block; background:red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

I'm using some selectors that aren't supported by old browsers, but you can accomplish the same concepts with classes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a88Cz/1/)

Comment: This is a pretty cool technique, but I was wanting the links to appear next to the link text (not over the link text) like in http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/wTwAd/2/. I will refer to this technique in the future though. Thank you.